# Parameters' value for weakly informative normal inverse wishart prior

Tags: bayesian, variance, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, conjugate-prior

What should one take as parameters for a normal inverse Wishart prior to be weakly informative? Is there a standard?
Thank you